# How to achieve IOS number keypad i.e similar to number keypad in android?

Tags: javascript, ios, html

When I change the type as number . I was seeing a keypad which is not similar to android/windows devices.

In IOS is looking like below

[image: In Ios i was observing like this.]

Where as in Android and other devices it looks like below.

.[image: Where as in Android and other devices]

I was checking the blogs and previous stack flow questions. In many of the place's guys are mentioning to change type="tel" . which is similar to type="tel" in android device. But no where i got the possibility of getting keypad similar to android through Javascript/container changes in IOS.

Answer (score 0):

This will give it to you:

```
<input type="number" pattern="\d*">
```

The problem with `<input type="tel">` is it will also give you the `*` and `#` characters

Comment: Is it possible to get without alphabets in the keypad.??

Comment: Yes, by doing what I just said - it's the `pattern="\d*"` that will give you the correct input. Visit this page on your device: https://jsfiddle.net/veuxzyyk/